# c++ return types for factory functions for Abstract Base Classes and Derived classes

Tags: c++, c++11, return-value, factory, shared-ptr

Suppose I need to have both factories for an abstract base class and its derived classes (I have no access to the actual constructors). Which would be the best construction in terms of efficiency and code style ?

1) Let all factories return a shared_ptr. This is uniform but leads to many unnecessary shared_ptrs for derived classes as they are directly dereferenced in the client code.

```
std::shared_ptr<Derived> createDerived(Argument arg) 
{ 
    return std::make_shared<Derived>(arg); 
}

std::shared_ptr<AbstractBaseClass> createABC(Argument arg)
{
    if (suchAndSo(arg))
        return createDerived(arg);
    else
        return nullptr; // or createSomeOtherDerivedClass
}

int main()
{
    Argument Arg;
    Derived d = *createDerived(arg);
    auto pAbc = createABC(arg);
}
```

2) Let the factories for derived classes return a value, and let the ABC factory return a shared ptr which is constructed by using make_shared and the copy constructor of Derived (which lead to many copy constructor calls)

```
Derived createDerived(Argument arg)
{
    return Derived(arg);
}

std::shared_ptr<AbstractBaseClass> createABC(Argument arg)
{
    if (suchAndSo(arg))
        return make_shared<AbstractBaseClass>(createDerived(arg));
    else
        return nullptr; // or createSomeOtherDerivedClass
}

int main()
{
    Argument Arg;
    Derived d = createDerived(arg);
    auto pAbc = createABC(arg);
}
```

Comment: Are you planning on having some polymorphic functions?

Comment: @doctorlove you can't have an *abstract* base class without a polymorphic (by which I assume you mean *virtual*) function, can you? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the ABC case, you can simply return a `unique_ptr`, to avoid overhead of `shared_ptr`. However, that is an option only if `~AbstractBaseClass` is virtual.

By returning a `unique_ptr`, you allow the caller to decide if the object needs to be shared.

---

When returning an object of concrete type, returning a value is indeed an excellent choice. That avoids the cost of dynamic allocation.

> which lead to many copy constructor calls

The value returning factory itself only copies if the object is not move-constructible and if the optimizer doesn't implement copy elision (which any decent optimizer does).

You can implement the abstract pointer returning factory without delegating to the value returning factory, and instead construct the object directly to avoid that copy (move).

Answer (score -1):

Both factory functions should return simple pointers. Shared pointer should be applied on their result.

Selecting the appropriate constructor using factory methods, in logical terms, is  something different than managing the object ownership (through shared pointers).

Comment: No, they should not return simple pointers, but rather Unique Pointers. Shared pointers says everyone shares the pointer, simple pointers doesn't say who shares it, but unique pointers makes it very clear its the receiver who owns it.